# Stop page refresh

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, onreadystatechange

I'm writing a small piece of code which takes input from a user via html form to then retrieve information (in xml) from a server (which is running locally) using **XMLHttpRequest**, once I get the information I output it into a list using the method I've written for the **onreadystatechange**. However once it's written the list to the page it automatically refreshes the page and the list disappears. I'm absolutely lost as to why it is doing this?! I've managed to forcefully stop the page refreshing using **window.onbeforeunload** and stopping the refresh, but I can't help but think there is a better way around this and that I must be doing something wrong. My code is as follows:

```
var xmlhttp=null;
```

function byObserver(){

```
var a = document.forms["byObserverForm"]["observerName"].value;
a = encodeURIComponent(a);

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
if (xmlhttp) {
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = onReadyStateByObserver;
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost:8004/birdobs/observer/" + a, false);
    xmlhttp.send();   
} 
return false;
```

}

```
function onReadyStateByObserver(){

if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){

    if (xmlhttp.status == 200){

        var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
        var observations = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("observation");

        if (observations.length != 0){

            // output into unordered list 
            var f = document.createDocumentFragment();
            var e = document.createElement("ul");
            f.appendChild(e);
            var ul = f.firstChild;

            for (i = 0; i<observations.length; i++) {
                var li = document.createElement("li");

                var te = document.createTextNode(observations[i].getAttribute("observer"));
                li.appendChild(te);
                ul.appendChild(li);
            }  // end for 
            document.getElementById("content").appendChild(f);

            window.onbeforeunload = function(){
                return "Refresh";
            }


        }
    }
} 
//have also tried return false here
```

}

Any help would be highly appreciated as I've spent so long trying to fix this, many thanks in advance! (I haven't included the HTML as I thought it wasn't needed, but please ask if it would help and I'll post it up!) I'll just finally add I'm running this in chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely because the browser is still submitting the form. You need to inform the browser that you do not wish for the default form submit handling to happen.

Returning `false` from your onsubmit method should do this.

** Update **

Presuming you are using the `onsubmit` handler and the function being called is `byObserver` then try the following:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<form ... onsubmit="return byObserver()">

// javascript
function byObserver() {
  ...
  return false;
}
```

Comment: No luck I'm afraid, but I think this is the reason

Comment: Nailed it! I had it written as onsubmit="byObserver()" I wish there was someway I could thank you properly! At the least consider a virtual hi5 coming your way.

Answer (score 2):

you should stop the default event when you submit the form, e.g. with `return false` at the end of the function called on submit. Maybe the page is refreshing because you're not stopping the `submit` event (and the browser is thus redirected to the page specified on `action` attribute of your form)

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply, I've tried returning false in both methods and fiddling with the action attribute in the form, but I'm still having no luck. I will edit my post to include the changes I made to the code.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the method that's invoked by submitting your form you need to `return false;`

It looks like the function being fired is `byObserver` and so you'd do the following:

```
function byObserver(){
   [...]
   return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I didn't have any luck with that though!?

Comment: I didn't realise you were attaching the even inline on the form. Posting your HTML would have made that clearer. Be aware that attaching events inline like this is considered bad practice.

Comment: Yes, I should have posted the html, my bad! Right I've definitely learnt something, will be sure not to do that again!